# Why are ASP.NET more secure than ASP Classic?

Tags: asp.net, security, asp-classic

I've read several places that ASP.NET are more secure than ASP Classic. But never seen any actual arguments of why.

Using a standard login system as an example.
The user sends a username and a password to the server via forms. This is done the same way in both languages. And in both languages the rest is done on the server.
Why choose ASP.NET over ASP Classic here?

Comment: Where have you read this?  There is at least just as many ways for a developer to inadvertantly  give a malicious attacker access in .NET as there is in Classic.

Comment: I would love to give a link to where I read it, but I really can't remember and can't seem to find it right now. It has just been nagging me since I read it about 9-12 months ago, which is why I asked. :) If it is not true (as you are saying?) then the answer to the question would be something like "It is not [...]"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned by ScottRFrost, [Request Validation](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/request-validation) protects against XSS as default. Personally, I'd prefer to turn this off and develop an application to use output sanitisation insead (e.g. HTML encode output to web pages, or properly encode and escape output used in JavaScript). This approach doesn't restrict user input so it does not restrict application functionality in the way Request Validation does. e.g. It will allow HTML to be entered into a field which will be displayed on a webpage instead of interpreted by a browser (imagine a HTML developers forum that didn't allow HTML to be posted). If you use this method in ASP.NET, you would use a very similar approach to standard ASP development in terms of variable output to the page.

To answer your point, during authentication (validating a username/password combination) there is not much difference between Classic ASP and ASP.NET. ASP.NET provides some user controls that can be dropped into a page, and also provides the [Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) model, but essentially you have to implement the logic for this either way.

ASP.NET also has authoriazation compenents included as standard, so it is possible to restrict access to your whole application or certain URL paths from settings in the web.config fille. This guards against a developer forgetting to include authorisation checks on a per page basis. Any finer grained access checks will still need to be manually handled in ASP.NET though.

ASP.NET also provides specialised folders such as /App_Data that cannot be read via the web server. This gives a convenient place to store application related files that should not be read directly via HTTP. You can do this manually in Classic ASP, but you would need to either store this directory outside of the web root or you would need to set local folder permissions so that these files cannot be read by the IIS user.

To summarise, I would not say ASP.NET is inherently more secure than Classic ASP, except for the fact that newbie developers are less likely to create an XSS vulnerable website in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET includes features like [Request Validation](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/request-validation) by default that limits some common script attacks.  You can do it yourself in classic ASP, but in .NET it's default.

Answer (score -1):

There may be may security issues. But I am concerned about one thing. It is about SQL injection. Asp.net has provided the facility of parameterized query and HTML encode decode technique. For more information click the link  [ASP.net security](http://dotnetwindow.blogspot.com/2008/08/sql-injection-and-xss-in-classic-asp.html)

Comment: This not an answer.  ADODB as used in ASP Classic also providers a developer with a way to use parameterized queries.  Equally there is nothing in .NET to prevent a developer from coding in an injection vunerability.

Comment: As @AnthonyWJones are saying you can use parameterized queries to stop injection attacks. You can also - if querying an ID - use a RegEdit expression to filter out all non-numeric characters. And if querying a string you can create a function to replace vulnerable characters with the correct ASCII character.